# Quadrivectors in relativity

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, vectors

This is what I understood about 4-vectors in relativity.

We define the contravariant and covariant vectors like this :
$$
A^\mu=\begin{bmatrix}
           A^0 \\
           A^1 \\
           A^2 \\
           A^3
         \end{bmatrix}$$

$$
A_\mu=\begin{bmatrix}
           A_0 \\
           A_1 \\
           A_2 \\
           A_3
         \end{bmatrix}$$

The relationship between them will be :

$$ 
A^\mu=\eta^{\mu \nu}A_\nu
$$

In +--- convention it will lead to :

$$
A^\mu=\begin{bmatrix}
           A_0 \\
           -A_1 \\
           -A_2 \\
           -A_3
         \end{bmatrix}$$

Great.

But it doesn't give me information on the "absolute" sign of 4-vectors. For example if I take the 4-position.

I have an even at time $t$ at space coordinates $(x,y,z)$.

Will I have $$X^\mu=\begin{bmatrix}
           t \\
           x \\
           y \\
           z
         \end{bmatrix}$$
Or

$$X_\mu=\begin{bmatrix}
           t \\
           x \\
           y \\
           z
         \end{bmatrix}$$
I think it is the first answer because $A^\mu$ should transform the same way that the "real" coordinates $(t,x,y,z)$ transform, but I am not totally sure?

Comment: In addition to the answer below: The concepts of covariance and contravariance are not restricted to relativity, they are much more fundamental (see for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvilinear_coordinates#Covariant_and_contravariant_bases). It may prove useful to take a look at what they mean in the familiar 3D case, and there is an excellent description in sec.2 of http://www.ita.uni-heidelberg.de/~dullemond/lectures/tensor/tensor.pdf. The generalization to Minkowski space becomes trivial.

Comment: Shouldn't your components of $X_\mu$ be $(t,-x,-y,-z)$?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that it doesn't really matter as long as you are consistent !

To see this, let us define $X^\mu = [a\ b\ c\ d]^T$ and $\tilde{X}^\mu = [a\ -b\ -c\ -d]^T$ we will see that these are equivalent up to a change of basis. Which proves that it is indeed irrelevant as long as we are consistent!

Expanding both vectors onto the basis of vectors in 4D Minkowski space $\{ \partial_t, \partial_x, \partial_y, \partial_z \}$ gives us:

$$ X = a\partial_t+b\partial_x+c\partial_y+d\partial_z\\\text{and}\\
\tilde{X}=a\partial_t - b\partial_x - c\partial_y-d\partial_z$$

Those two vectors are indeed equivalent up to an inversion of the spatial part of the manifold.

Also, if I may give you a little tip. $X^\mu$ and $X_\mu$ are contractible to a scalar you can stress this when going to matrix notation by writing: $X^\mu = [...]$ and $X_\mu = [...]^T$.

I hope this helps. Feel free to ask questions if you are still confused

Comment: Hmmm but if I have a physical event $(t,x,y,z)$, it must transform using the contravariant $\Lambda$ physically. So if I say $X_\mu=(t,x,y,z)$ I will have my physical event that will transform with a $\Lambda$ covariant so I may end with a problem no ?
Thank you for your answer

Comment: It is indeed somewhat more natural to define $X^\mu = (t,x,y,z)$ since we would get $X = t\partial_t + x\partial_x + ... $ according to our intuition. You should realize that measuring vectors is extremely difficult(direct measurement is impossible as far as I know) such that we can only measure scalars.

It than doesn't matter weather which one has the - as long as one of the two has it !

You shouldn't really think about this to much to be honest. This is the kind of things that just works out ;)